# How to create text search configuration if not exists on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to create text search configuration but only when it doesn't exists? For instance, like the other create statements:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION IF NOT EXISTS text_without_accent (COPY = simple);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `DO` statement and capture errors:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ...
EXCEPTION
   WHEN unique_violation THEN
      NULL;  -- ignore error
END;$$;
```

Comment: Not just for this use case, but for many others, this is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drop it first, and then create it again:

```
DROP TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION IF EXISTS text_without_accent cascade;
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION text_without_accent (COPY = simple);
```